# XML Parsing - Search for specific elements

Tags: java, xml, parsing, search

I have an XML document that I need to parse in order to extract specific values from it.
The schema is similar to this one:

```
    <sequence tag="771b,1030" vr="SQ" card="2" len="988" name="axial_length_values_sequence">
        <item card="6" len="486">
            <element tag="771b,0000" vr="UL" vm="1" len="4" name="PrivateGroupLength">474</element>
            <element tag="771b,0010" vr="LO" vm="1" len="6" name="PrivateCreator">99CZM</element>
            <element tag="771b,1008" vr="CS" vm="1" len="2" name="laterality">R</element>
            <element tag="771b,1043" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_al">27.649999999999999</element>
            <element tag="771b,1044" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_snr">272.5</element>
        </item>
        <item card="6" len="486">
            <element tag="771b,0000" vr="UL" vm="1" len="4" name="PrivateGroupLength">474</element>
            <element tag="771b,0010" vr="LO" vm="1" len="6" name="PrivateCreator">99CZM</element>
            <element tag="771b,1008" vr="CS" vm="1" len="2" name="laterality">L</element>
            <element tag="771b,1043" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_al">27.0100000000000016</element>
            <element tag="771b,1044" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_snr">151.90000000000001</element>
        </item>
    </sequence>
    <sequence tag="771b,1032" vr="SQ" card="2" len="1268" name="keratometer_values_sequence">
        <item card="13" len="626">
            <element tag="771b,0000" vr="UL" vm="1" len="4" name="PrivateGroupLength">614</element>
            <element tag="771b,0010" vr="LO" vm="1" len="6" name="PrivateCreator">99CZM</element>
            <element tag="771b,1008" vr="CS" vm="1" len="2" name="laterality">R</element>
            <element tag="771b,1016" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="refractive_index">1.3374999999999999</element>
            <element tag="771b,1017" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="quali_tag">0</element>
            <element tag="771b,1049" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_r1">8.5199999999999996</element>
            <element tag="771b,104a" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_d1">39.609999999999999</element>
            <element tag="771b,104b" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_a1">174</element>
            <element tag="771b,104c" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_r2">8.4499999999999993</element>
            <element tag="771b,104d" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_d2">39.939999999999998</element>
            <element tag="771b,104e" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_a2">84</element>
            <element tag="771b,104f" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_zyl">0.33000000000000003</element>
        </item>
        <item card="13" len="626">
            <element tag="771b,0000" vr="UL" vm="1" len="4" name="PrivateGroupLength">614</element>
            <element tag="771b,0010" vr="LO" vm="1" len="6" name="PrivateCreator">99CZM</element>
            <element tag="771b,1008" vr="CS" vm="1" len="2" name="laterality">L</element>
            <element tag="771b,1016" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="refractive_index">1.3374999999999999</element>
            <element tag="771b,1017" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="quali_tag">0.01</element>
            <element tag="771b,1049" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_r1">8.4800000000000004</element>
            <element tag="771b,104a" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_d1">39.799999999999997</element>
            <element tag="771b,104b" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_a1">167</element>
            <element tag="771b,104c" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_r2">8.3399999999999999</element>
            <element tag="771b,104d" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_d2">40.469999999999999</element>
            <element tag="771b,104e" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_a2">77</element>
            <element tag="771b,104f" vr="FD" vm="1" len="8" name="mean_value_zyl">0.67000000000000002</element>
        </item>
    </sequence>
```

There other 4 "sequence" elements to parse.

For each "sequence" element I need to extract the value of:
    R

and according to the value (if R or L) I need to save the a specific value twice, once for the Left ("L") and once for the right ("R") 
e.g. :
the right value for tag="771b,1044" will be :
**"272.5"** 
and for the left will be :
**"151.90000000000001"**

I am loosing my mind!!!! Can anyone help me? 
I can get single values if I search for a specific tag, but I cannot find how to search first for "R" then only for the value associated to "R" and then repeat the search for "L" and get the associated values!!! Consider that "R" is not always the first element (it could also be "L").
Any help will be very much appreciated. thank you all in advance !!

Comment: I tried searching for specific Elements using DOM, and I can get one specific tag, but in my case the tags are not unique. "laterality" exists twice for each "Item card" and also <element tag="771b,1043" exists twice for each "item card".

Comment: Did my answer resolve the issue? If so, please consider accepting it as an answer, otherwise please post a follow up comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JSOUP: https://jsoup.org/

I copied your xml into a file test.xml and parsed it with JSOUP:

```
final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File(".\\test.xml"), "UTF-8");

String tag;
BigDecimal left=new BigDecimal(0);
BigDecimal right=new BigDecimal(0);

for (Element sequence : doc.select("sequence")) {
    tag = sequence.attr("tag");

    for (Element item : sequence.select("element[name='laterality']")) {

        String value="";

        if(tag.equals("771b,1030")) value = item.siblingElements().select("element[name='mean_value_snr']").text();
        //specify correct name for other sequences here

        if(!value.isEmpty()){
            if(item.text().equals("L")) left = new BigDecimal(value);
            if(item.text().equals("R")) right = new BigDecimal(value);
        }else{
            left=new BigDecimal(0);
            right=new BigDecimal(0);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(tag + ": " + "L mean_value=" + left + " | R mean_value=" + right);
}
```

prints out:

```
771b,1030: L mean_value=151.90000000000001 | R mean_value=272.5
771b,1032: L mean_value=0 | R mean_value=0
```

**UPDATE:** replaced double with BigDecimal to avoid losing precision

Comment: You are just the BEST! thank you very much for this solution! It works perfectly! I started loosing hope (and my mind!), and you made it so easy! Thanky again!